# Facebook API 'Events Popular In Your Network'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to utilise the Facebook Graph API to access the section 'Events Popular In Your Network'. However, I cannot seem to find an endpoint that gives access to these. Is there a possible way to get hold of this information? The section is accessed by clicking 'Events' and scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, there is not an specific endpoint for that.

If you want, you might be able to build something similar using events ([events docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event/)). Getting friends events, checking attendees ([attending endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event/attending)) and ranking them (popular in this case means more friends attending to the event).

I hope it helps.